# Orthogonal basis for $L_2 [0,\frac {\pi}{2}]$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am supposed to show that $\{sin((2n-1)x)\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ is an orthogonal basis for $L_2[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

I know how to show that each function is orthogonal to the other but I dont know how to prove it is dense.

I can use the fact that $\{1,sin(nx),cos(nx)\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ is an orthogonal basis for $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: Start with a function $f$ on $[0,\pi/2]$. Extend it to $[0,\pi]$ to be even across $x=\pi/2$. Then extend the extension to $[-\pi,\pi]$ as an odd function across $x=0$. Find the Fourier coefficients of the new function.

Comment: i will try thanx!